# Pjax adds id to url

Tags: jquery, pjax

I am using jquery with pjax for loading pages, everything works quite well, except that pjax adds some numbers to url (supposed to to be an unique ID, because with every query it is incremented).
Example url after clicking pjax link:

> `http://localhost/mylink?_=1383575943800`

I add pjax support for links like this:

> $(document).pjax('.box ul a', '#response');

How to remove that GET variable "_"?
Thank you

Comment: Disable caching on the ajax call. i'm unfamiliar how to do that with pjax, but it's likely documented.

Comment: This is a part from my response headers: 'Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate'. Didn't help

Comment: Right, but you need to change client side settings. The client is what's setting that url param. aka `$.pjax`, or the underlying `$.ajax` that `$.pjax` relies on.

Comment: I resolved the problem(answered below), but I don't understand why, do you have any ideas?

Comment: jQuery appends a url parameter `?_=$.now()` to prevent caching. Unless you specifically disable it, it's always going to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the answer, I had used jquery ajax before, so I had a setup for jquery ajax cache

> $.ajaxSetup ({
>           cache: false
>       });

I removed this line of code and everything works great. But I still can't understand why.